# Finding an equivalence relation given an undefined set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to define a relation $R$ on the set $X$ with a cardinality of $10$ with 10 elements such that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

I can either define a property on $X$ or simply list the elements of $R$.

Then I must find the different equivalence classes of $R$ and show their connection to a partition of $X$

So, if I let $X = \{x\;|\;x=\{1,2,...,10\}\text{ and }x\;mod\;3=2\}$

Could a possible $R$ be $\{(2,2),(2,5),(2,8),(5,2),(5,5),(5,8),(8,2),(8,5),(8,8)\}$?

Though very unsure, I believe the equivalence class to be just $\{2,5,8\}$ which is a subset of $X$

Comment: Partition $X$ into any subsets of $X$, and define equivalence relation on $X$ to be $xRy \iff \text{$x,y$ are in the same subset of $X$}$

Comment: An equivalence relation on your set of $10$ elements has to be reflexive. The simplest way to make your relation reflexive is to throw in $(1,1)$, $(3,3)$, and so on. That would give use one equivalence class with $3$ points and $7$ with one point each.

Comment: @AndreNicolas The (possible?) set $R$ I gave contains $(2,2)$,$ (5,5)$ and $(8,8)$ which are all reflexive. I believe my $R$ is an equivalence relation of $X$. I don't even know if my $X$ is what it's supposed to be

Comment: There are many equivalence relations on $X$, each obtained by dividing $X$ into parts. For the reason I described earlier, yours is not an equivalence relation on $X$.

Comment: Your definition of $X$ isn't quite right. Note that saying $X = \{x\mid x = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \dotsc \}$, says that $x$ itself *is* $\{1,2,\dotsc 10\}$, and then $x$ *mod* $3$ makes no sense as $x$ is a set. You want "$x\in$" not "$x=$".

Comment: What do you mean by "the equivalent class? $\{2,5,8\}$ is one of the equivalence classes, but there are others, and every element of $X$ appears in one (and only one) of them.

Comment: @AndreNicolas So based on the statement 'Define a property on $X$ or simply list the elements of $R$' do I need to just define $X$ as say $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and then do the Relation on that with say $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ or would it need to involve every single element of $X$?

Comment: @BrianO Oh I see my error there now. Ah I see, I thought I only defined the equivalence class from $R$. So must my $R$ contain every element of $X$?

Comment: Every single element must be mentioned, but some (maybe all) occur only as $(a,a)$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Oh I see now! So I don't necessarily need $(1,3)$ but if it was used I would need $(3,1)$. I think the problem I've had is I didn't define $X$ when I answered this the first time, but my understanding otherwise has been okay